# Ruby error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I am ruby beginner. I am use proc class but I am getting error.

```
class Timeline
    attr_accessor :tweets

    def each(&block)  # Block into the proc
        tweets.each(&block) # proc back into the block 
    end
end
timeline = Timeline.new(tweets)
timeline.each do |tweet|
    puts tweet
end
```

Getting error :-

```
`each': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How to solve this error? Please tell us!

Comment: your `@tweets` variable is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `attr_accessor :tweets`, you just define 2 instance methods:

```
def tweets
  @tweets
end

def tweets=(tweets)
  @tweets = tweets
end
```

When you call `tweets` inside the `each` method, you just call method with this name, not a local variable, so you should set @tweets in the `initialize` method because right now your `@tweets` variable is not set:

```
class Timeline
  attr_accessor :tweets # this is just a nice syntax for instance variable setter 
                        # and getter

  def initialize(tweets)
    @tweets = tweets
  end 

  def each(&block)  # Block into the proc
    tweets.each(&block) # proc back into the block 
  end
end
```

Comment: This code does not work. Error :- test-1.rb:51:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `tweets' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: maybe you should define `tweets`?

Comment: @harleenkaur,  `timeline = Timeline.new(tweets)` in this line